# Dump series back into InfluxDB after querying with replaced field value

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-python

### Scenario

I want to send data to an MQTT Broker (Cloud) by querying measurements from InfluxDB.

I have a **field** in the schema which is called `status`. It can either be `1` or `0`. `status=0` indicated that series has not been sent to the cloud. If I get an acknowlegdment from the MQTT Broker then I wish to rewrite the query back into the database with `status=1`.

As mentioned in [FAQs for InfluxDB regarding Duplicate data](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-does-influxdb-handle-duplicate-points) If the information has the same timestamp as the previous query but with a different field value => then the update field will be shown.

In order to test this I created the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE dummy
USE dummy
INSERT meas_1, type=t1, status=0,value=123 1536157064275338300
```

query:

```
SELECT * FROM meas_1
```

provides

```
time                status type value         
1536157064275338300 0      t1   234
```

now if I want to **overwrite** the series I do the following:

```
INSERT meas_1, type=t1, status=1,value=123 1536157064275338300
```

which will overwrite the series

```
 time                status type value         
 1536157064275338300 1      t1   234
```

(Note: this is not possible via **Tags** currently in InfluxDB)

#### Usage

1. Query some information using the client with `"status"=0`.
2. Restructure JSON to be sent to the cloud
3. Send the information to cloud
4. If successful then write the output from Step 1. back into the DB but with `status=1`.

I am using the [`InfluxDBClient Python3`](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html) to create the Application (MQTT + InfluxDB)

Within the [`write_points` API](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdb.InfluxDBClient.write_points) there is a parameter which mentions `batch_size` which require `int` as input.

I am not sure how can I use this with the Application that I want. Can someone guide me with this or with the Schema of the DB so that I can upload actual and non-redundant information to the cloud ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `batch_size` is actually the length of the list of the measurements that needs to passed to `write_points`.

### Steps

1. Create client and query from measurement (here, we query gps information)

   ```
   client = InfluxDBClient(database='dummy')

   op = client.query('SELECT * FROM gps WHERE "status"=0', epoch='ns')
   ```
2. Make the `ResultSet` into a list:

   ```
    batch = list(op.get_points('gps'))
   ```
3. create an empty list for update

   ```
    updated_batch = []
   ```
4. parse through each measurement and change the `status` flag to `1`. Note, default values in InfluxDB are float

   ```
      for each in batch:
   new_mes = {
   'measurement': 'gps',
   'tags': {
   'type': 'gps'
   },
   'time': each['time'],
   'fields': {
     'lat': float(each['lat']),
     'lon': float(each['lon']),
     'alt': float(each['alt']),
     'status': float(1)
   }
   }
   updated_batch.append(new_mes)
   ```
5. Finally dump the points back via the client with `batch_size` as the length of the `updated_batch`

   ```
   client.write_points(updated_batch, batch_size=len(updated_batch))
   ```

This overwrites the series because it contains the same timestamps with `status` field set to `1`